# In linux, how can I get my IP address - ifconfig and ip addr show are not working

Tags: linux, ip-address, tcpip

This should be simple, but the machines we ssh into don't seem to have the regular commands.

Are there any other simple ways I can use to get my IP?

Comment: tried /sbin/ifconfig ?

Comment: Use an ioctl: http://mail.nl.linux.org/kernelnewbies/2003-05/msg00090.html

Comment: I presume you need to get this programmatically, right, and you're not just trying to find out what the IP is? There are any number of ways to do either.

Comment: I like how so many answers and comments offer ifconfig when the title says it's not working. However, instead of saying "not working" it would be helpful if you posted error messages or other information that shows how the result differs from the expectation.

Comment: +1 for /sbin/ifconfig. It is most probably that `ifconfig` is not in your PATH, so try using it with full path to command.

Comment: /sbin/ifconfig ... damn solaris!

Comment: Note that while `/sbin/ifconfig` is the most frequetly solution to this problem, there are cases where ifconfig is genuinely not installed, like minimalist docker images or embedded systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `/sbin/ifconfig`. you can also try searching in `/proc/net`

Answer (score 5):

try with

`ip address`

Just to know, post a uname -a :)

Answer (score 4):

**ifconfig** will work. but you need to be a super user.

try this command
**hostname -i**

even **netstat -rn** also will work. but it will display the routing table also along with IP.

Comment: No, you don't have to be superuser to retrieve the information.

Comment: thanks, "hostname -i" is the one working also on a Kubernetes pod

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ ifconfig eth0
```

(or replace eth0 with the device you're using)
Look for: `inet addr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
That's your IP addy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, do you mean the IP in LAN?

If you can ssh in the box [by typing "ssh address_of_the_box"], you can just ping the address_of_the_box in another box, then you can get it...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ssh to access the machine, you must have the hostname.  So you should be able to look up the ip address on some other machine using, for example `dig hostname`.